# Azure CDN is redirecting traffic with a custom domain

Tags: azure, dns, cdn, azure-cdn

I have a setup like this:

A website at domain `abc.com`

Azure CDN points to it. So if you go to `abc.azuredge.net` you see `abc.com` 
content. In the URL bar you see `abc.azuredge.net`.

I have another domain, `qwe.com`, I want `abc.qwe.com` to be the custom domain for the CDN endpoint.
In `qwe` DNS settings, I set a CNAME record, for `abc` to point to `abc.azuredge.net`.
I add the `abc.qwe.com` as a custom domain in the CDN endpoint.

**My expectation**:
I go to `abc.qwe.com`. I see `abc.com` content, from `abc.qwe.com` domain.

**What happens**: I go to `abc.qwe.com`, it responds with a parmanent redirect to `abc.com`.

Did I miss configured something, or it's supposed to work this way? I don't understand why it doesn't do a redirect on `abc.azureedge.net`, but if I add a layer on top of it, suddenly it just redirects to the origin.

Comment: `but if I add a layer on top of it, suddenly it just redirects to the origin.` what do you mean? and how do you do that?

Comment: I have the same issue. Just tried to set up a CDN with custom domain, but all it does is redirect to the origin. Using the xxx.azureedge.net domain works fine.

@NancyXiong I think that Erndob just means that the "layer" is having a custom domain.

Comment: @ErikH I've added an answer to explain what happened for me, I hope it ends up being helpful for you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it ended up being not related to CDN. It was actually rules on a server that were doing a redirect under certain conditions, e.g. http to https, or www redirect.

As a side note, https redirect can be tricky. Now chrome uses https by default, so if you type in the url, it will go to https, thus no redirect. But if you select your custom domain text in azure portal and choose "go to xxx", it will actually go to http version, which will result in a redirect. So you might be under impression that you are going to https and it was redirecting, when in fact it was http.

I was planning to delete the question, but Erik H commented that he's having same issue so I decided to self-answer. Maybe it will help someone.

Comment: Thanks Erndob, it was a similar issue for me. That, and the fact that Chrome is caching 301 redirects, made me confused :-)